# How to upload audio file to Firebase Storage?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-storage

> I'm trying to upload audio file to Firebase Storage in my Ionic2 project.

First I recorded a audio file using Media plugin (Cordova plugin), and this file is playing well. From the Android storage and from the media plugin method (this.media.play()...;).

Second I need to push the recorded file to Firebase Storage.

**this is my code:**

```
  let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  let metadata = {
     contentType: 'audio/mp3',
   };
  let filePath = `${this.file.externalDataDirectory}`+`${this.fileName}`;
  const voiceRef = storageRef.child(`voices/${this.fileName}`);  
  var blob = new Blob([filePath], {type: 'audio/mp3'});
  voiceRef.put(blob);
```

> After reading the Firebase doc, I can push blob to Firebase.

The file is successfully pushed to Firebase Storage with empty data (95 Byte).

**this is screenshot:**[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem isn't a Firebase issue

My problem is solved by using the **File** cordova plugin method (`readAsDataURL()`) and the  `putString(fileBase64,firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL)` method.

First, I create a file reference: 
`let filePath = "this.file.externalDataDirectory" + "this.fileName";`

Then I transform the file to a base64 string by using the **readAsDataURL** method that returns a promise containing the file as a string base64. Also, I push the file to Firebase using the **putString** method that has two parameters the File that returned by the **readAsDataURL** and the second is firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL.

My Final code:

```
  let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  let metadata = {
    contentType: 'audio/mp3',
  };
  let filePath = `${this.file.externalDataDirectory}` + `${this.fileName}`;
  this.file.readAsDataURL(this.file.externalDataDirectory, this.fileName).then((file) => {
    let voiceRef = storageRef.child(`voices/${this.fileName}`).putString(file, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL);
    voiceRef.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, (snapshot) => {
      console.log("uploading");
    }, (e) => {
      reject(e);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
    }, () => {
      var downloadURL = voiceRef.snapshot.downloadURL;
      resolve(downloadURL);
    });
  });
```

That's working fine for me.
Thanks.